# Is there a way to use Arduino CLI to compile sketch.ino to a .bin file?

Tags: arduino, command-line-interface, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, ota

I want to upload a sketch on my Wemos D1 mini, via OTA using Arduino CLI or any other solution, but not using Arudino IDE, because i need to make the process self running. (1. get the code from web / 2. save it to a sketch.ino file / 3. compile it to a .bin file using a script, 4. upload it using espota.py)

I can upload via ITA a sketch with espota.py command, but i need to have an already compiled .bin file, which i get using Arduino IDE, so is not what i want.

CMD:
~/Sketch> python espota.py -d -i ip_esp8266 -f sketch.bin

ip_esp8266 e.g. = 192.168.1.101
sketch.bin = the file generated from Arduino IDE -> Sketch -> Export compiled Binary

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli

Answer (score 7):

I'm using a headless raspberry pi as my programmer as my laptop is rather locked down. I'm not familiar with the `espota.py`, but this process below works fully from the command line to compile and upload .ino code. The [`arduino-cli`](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli) is pretty full featured and I've had success on it with Adafruit's Huzzah (using an FTDI cable) and the Wemos D1 Mini (direct USB)

The first thing to do is add esp8266 boards. I'm not exactly sure how I did this, but you can see which additional boards are available with the `config dump` command:

```
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ arduino-cli config dump
proxy_type: auto
sketchbook_path: /home/pi/Arduino
arduino_data: /home/pi/.arduino15
```

So I crack open the `/home/pi/.arduino15/` directory and there is a `arduino-cli.yaml` file. In there, I add the ESP8266 package, making the `arduino-cli.yaml` look like this:

```
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ cat /home/pi/.arduino15/arduino-cli.yaml 
proxy_type: auto
sketchbook_path: /home/pi/Arduino
arduino_data: /home/pi/.arduino15
board_manager:
  additional_urls:
  - http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
```

(I fought with this a couple times, so that may not be 100% but the `config dump` should reflect what data directory it uses and in there should be a .yaml file with the additional_urls)

Without the D1 plugged in, run this to see what ports are listed:

```
arduino-cli board list
```

Then plug in the D1 and the output should be something like:

```
Port         Type              Board Name FQBN Core
/dev/ttyAMA0 Serial Port       Unknown             
/dev/ttyUSB0 Serial Port (USB) Unknown
```

For both the Huzzah and the D1 I get that Board Name unknown, but they are both ESP8266 boards. The `board listall` command will show all the boards and their FQBN, which you'll need for compiling and uploading:

```
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ arduino-cli board listall
Board Name                        FQBN                            
4D Systems gen4 IoD Range         esp8266:esp8266:gen4iod         
Adafruit Circuit Playground       arduino:avr:circuitplay32u4cat  
Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266   esp8266:esp8266:huzzah  

....snip.....

LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 R2 & mini         esp8266:esp8266:d1_mini         
LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 mini Lite         esp8266:esp8266:d1_mini_lite    
LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 mini Pro          esp8266:esp8266:d1_mini_pro    
WeMos D1 R1                       esp8266:esp8266:d1
```

From there, I copy the FQBN.
Then (or before maybe), I create a new sketch:

```
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ arduino-cli sketch new MyFirstSketch
Sketch created in: /home/pi/sketchbook/MyFirstSketch
```

Then edit the .ino file and complile:

```
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ vim ./MyFirstSketch/MyFirstSketch.ino 
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ 
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ SKETCH=MyFirstSketch
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ arduino-cli compile --fqbn esp8266:esp8266:d1_mini $SKETCH
Sketch uses 257680 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 26572 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55348 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $
```

Then upload:

```
pi@dogwood:~/sketchbook $ arduino-cli upload -p /dev/ttyUSB0 --fqbn esp8266:esp8266:d1_mini $SKETCH
No new serial port detected.
esptool.py v2.6
2.6
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: ec:fa:bc:61:0e:31
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 261840 bytes to 191242...
Wrote 261840 bytes (191242 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 7.4 seconds (effective 282.8 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

I had to reset the Huzzah after uploading, but the D1 mini did fine after the upload and correctly ran my code.

To get the serial monitor use something like `screen` like so:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Answer (score 3):

As of current version, you can do the following to get the output files:

```
arduino-cli compile --fqbn arduino:avr:uno my_arduino_program.ino --output-dir ./
```

All the binary and artifact files will be in the current directory.

However, the manual page shows that we should be able to just pass `-o` and get the binary output. But it did not work for my currently downloaded master branch `arduino-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Search for AVRDUDE, AVRDUDE can be used effectively via the command line.